# Covert time format from 24hr time to seconds into day.

Tags: vba, excel

I want to switch format from hh:mm:ss to seconds into day. So I want to input a 24-hour time and have it return an integer seconds into day. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TIMEVALUE` formula to convert your time into a portion of a day (0-1), then multiply by hours, minutes, and seconds. Then to get a whole number, `ROUND` it.

```
=ROUND(TIMEVALUE(<yourtimehere>) * 24 * 60 * 60)
```